# How can we access the derived class instance in function callback, if we used the base class instance in typedef

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a base class (IndicatorRenderDetails) and two derived classes (EmaIndicatorRenderDetails, SmaIndicatorRenderDetails) derived from a base class. Then, I have created typedef by using base class instance. My questions are that when I access the derived class instance in the function callback, I am unable to access its values and getting errors like below

The argument type 'Null Function(EmaIndicatorRenderDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(IndicatorRenderDetails)'

So, how can we avoid this error and access the derived class instance in the callback?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: ChartTestWidget(
            technicalIndicators: <TechinicalIndicator>[
              TechinicalIndicator(
                  onIndicatorRender: (IndicatorRenderDetails details) {
                print(details.baseName);
              }),
              EmaTechinicalIndicator(
                  onIndicatorRender: (EmaIndicatorRenderDetails details) {
                print(details.emaIndicatorName);
              }),
              SmaTechinicalIndicator(
                  onIndicatorRender: (SmaIndicatorRenderDetails details) {
                print(details.smaIndicatorName);
              })
            ],
            child: Center(
                child: Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100, width: 100))));
  }
}

class ChartTestWidget extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const ChartTestWidget({Widget child, this.technicalIndicators})
      : super(child: child);

  //final EmployeeCallback employeeCallback;

  final List<TechinicalIndicator> technicalIndicators;

  @override
  RenderProxyBox createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return ChartTestWidgetRenderProxyBox(this);
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, covariant RenderObject renderObject) {
    super.updateRenderObject(context, renderObject);
  }
}

class ChartTestWidgetRenderProxyBox extends RenderProxyBox {
  ChartTestWidgetRenderProxyBox(this.testWidget, {RenderBox child})
      : super(child);

  final ChartTestWidget testWidget;

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    if (child != null) {
      child.layout(constraints, parentUsesSize: true);
      size = child.size;
    }
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    if (testWidget.technicalIndicators != null &&
        testWidget.technicalIndicators.isNotEmpty) {
      for (final TechinicalIndicator technicalIndicator
          in testWidget.technicalIndicators) {
        if (technicalIndicator is EmaTechinicalIndicator) {
          final EmaIndicatorRenderDetails emaIndicatorRenderDetails =
              EmaIndicatorRenderDetails(
                  'emaTechnicalIndicator', 'technicalIndicator');
          technicalIndicator.onIndicatorRender(emaIndicatorRenderDetails);
        } else if (technicalIndicator is SmaTechinicalIndicator) {
          final SmaIndicatorRenderDetails smaIndicatorRenderDetails =
              SmaIndicatorRenderDetails(
                  'smaTechnicalIndicator', 'technicalIndicator');
          technicalIndicator.onIndicatorRender(smaIndicatorRenderDetails);
        } else if (technicalIndicator is TechinicalIndicator) {
          final IndicatorRenderDetails indicatorRenderDetails =
              IndicatorRenderDetails(baseName: 'technicalIndicator');
          technicalIndicator.onIndicatorRender(indicatorRenderDetails);
        }
      }
    }
    super.paint(context, offset);
  }
}

class TechinicalIndicator {
  TechinicalIndicator({this.onIndicatorRender});
  final IndicatorCallback onIndicatorRender;
}

class EmaTechinicalIndicator extends TechinicalIndicator {
  EmaTechinicalIndicator({IndicatorCallback onIndicatorRender})
      : super(onIndicatorRender: onIndicatorRender);
}

class SmaTechinicalIndicator extends TechinicalIndicator {
  SmaTechinicalIndicator({IndicatorCallback onIndicatorRender})
      : super(onIndicatorRender: onIndicatorRender);
}

class IndicatorRenderDetails {
  IndicatorRenderDetails({this.baseName});
  final String baseName;
}

class EmaIndicatorRenderDetails extends IndicatorRenderDetails {
  EmaIndicatorRenderDetails(this.emaIndicatorName, String baseName)
      : super(baseName: baseName);
  final String emaIndicatorName;
}

class SmaIndicatorRenderDetails extends IndicatorRenderDetails {
  SmaIndicatorRenderDetails(this.smaIndicatorName, String baseName)
      : super(baseName: baseName);
  final String smaIndicatorName;
}

typedef IndicatorCallback<T> = void Function(IndicatorRenderDetails details);
```

[image: Sample_image]

Comment: `Function(Derived)` can't be substituted for `Function(Base)`, because `Function(Base)` is allowed to be called with any `Base`.  What would happen if it's called with some other object that derived from `Base`?  Some possible fixes: 1. If you're sure that the callbacks can be invoked only with the correct `Derived` type, use the [`covariant` keyword](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems#the-covariant-keyword). 2. Make your callbacks take the base class as the argument type and explicitly cast.

Comment: 3. Your `IndicatorCallback` `typedef` is generic, but you don't actually do anything with `T`.  You perhaps could change it to `typedef IndicatorCallback<T> = void Function(T details);` (and specify the type parameter wherever you use it).